# How to setup Liveness in the Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new to the Kubernetes. I would like to setup liveness for my EKS kubernetest cluster. I went through the documentation below
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/
I have few questions to setup the above

1. When I apply liveness-exec do I need mention any particular namespace for example
   `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/probe/exec-liveness.yaml -n kube-system`
2. Can I use yaml file directly from k8s.io/example or I need to clone in my local
3. How these whole things works? What I understand so far is

   a) When we deploy the pod, it will create a container and create /tmp/healthy file and then delete the container

   b) It will run after 30 seconds and redo the same thing from step 3a

I followed above steps and I am getting an error saying 
cat:

```
can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory
```

This post may sound repetitive but I tried going through the previous post but unable to find the solutions. Please help

Answer (score 1):

> 1) When I apply liveness-exec do I need mention any particular namespace
>   for example kubectl apply -f
>   https://k8s.io/examples/pods/probe/exec-liveness.yaml -n kube-system

If you specify a namespace in the apply command the pod will be created in that namespace, provided the namespace exist. If you don't specify a namespace (by command line or in the pod yaml definition) then the pod will be created in the default namespace

> 2) Can I use yaml file directly from k8s.io/example or I need to clone
>   in my local

You can apply it direcly from k8s.io/example.

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/probe/exec-liveness.yaml
```

> 3) How these whole things works? What I understand so far is
>
> a) When we deploy the pod, it will create a container and create
>   /tmp/healthy file and then delete the container
>
> b) It will run after 30 seconds and redo the same thing from step 3a

I think that the idea of the example is just to show how liveness probes work and how your pod will be restarted after the test fails, so the commands executed are a bit artificial. I think the error you see is simply the probe failing the check "cat /tmp/healthy"

Answer (score 0):

The `livenessProbe` in conjunction with the `readynessProbe` are two parameters that you need to put in your own yaml definition as a container spec, the example files are only to exemplify it.

An example of `livenessProbe` for a grafana service colud be:

```
livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 10
    httpGet:
      path: /api/health
      port: 3000
      scheme: HTTP
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    periodSeconds: 10
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 30
```

Not all the parameters are needed you have to think about how to do it better for your services.

Answer (score 0):

The "apply" command from the Kubernetes Rest client(kubectl) can have either a local or remote file. **Liveness** is proof of availability and **readness** is proof of pod readiness. From the moment the pod is created **livenessProbe** runs every 5 seconds as per **periodSeconds** configured, the "rm -rf / tmp / healthy" command runs after 30 seconds of sleep, so there will come a time that the proof of Life will not find the file and will generate an alert.

Hope this helps.